# Argument 3 matches multiple formal arguments with ‘mediate’ function using ‘psych’ package

Tags: r, compiler-errors

Please help! Trying to conduct a mediation model using the psych package following the code below. It worked originally and now I keep getting the error

> argument 3 matches multiple arguments

```
require(psych)
Mediation1<-mediate(“lifestyle", "Gender", m=c(“smoker"), data= lifedata, std=TRUE, n.iter=5000, plot= F)
Mediation1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making sure it is through the psych package?

I got the same error when it was automatically being run through the mediation package.

```
Try psych::mediate(“lifestyle", "Gender", m=c(“smoker"), data= lifedata, std=TRUE, n.iter=5000, plot= F)
```

Hope that helps you!